# How to color status bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

How can I color status bar I got a navigation bar that disappear when I Scroll my table but cells go under status bar...

Here there is my navigation controller

```
class NavigationController : UINavigationController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Utility().coloreTitolo()
          UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false;
          UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
          navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
}
```

I try this code but when I scroll down view is displayed too...

```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    let statusBar = UIView(frame:
        CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 20.0)
    )
    statusBar.backgroundColor = Utility().coloreTitolo()
    statusBar.tag = 100;

    if(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(scrollView).y > 0)
    {
        self.view.addSubview(statusBar)
    }
    else
    {
        let subViews = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews
        for subview in subViews!
        {
            if (subview.tag == 100) {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to color the text in the status bar?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't properly understand the wording of your question, but from what I gathered you're wanting to make the background of your UINavigationBar white, so you can't see objects passing behind it.

Try adding this to your ViewController(s) in the viewWillAppear() function:

```
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.view.addSubview(view)
```

Tell me if that works for you.

Edit:
Here's what I've put together, however I haven't tried it so I don't know the outcome.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: "testForHidden", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func testForHidden() {

    let fakebar = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
    fakebar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    switch navigationController?.navigationBarHidden {
    case true?:
        self.view.addSubview(fakebar)
    case false?:
        fakebar.removeFromSuperview()
    default: break
    }

}
```

Comment: It work but when I don't scroll up i got this view under the navigation bar...i want this view to appear only when navigation bar is "hidden"

Comment: @MarcoCastano you can always use an `NSTimer` to run a function which checks if you're scrolled past a point, and `if` you're gotten to that point then use an `if` statement to run the code in that same function.

Comment: can u write some code ? I added and edit but can't figure this out...:/

Comment: Hey, @MarcoCastano did you figure it out? Sorry I've been away.

Comment: @MarcoCastano I'll whip something up for you. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @MarcoCastano try now. (I haven't tried that, sorry.)

Comment: ehm thank you for this code..I try it right now and app doesn't start due to while loop...

Comment: Let me fix that sorry ;o

Comment: Fixed. Try again. I should have realized that would happen with the while loop.

Comment: It works until I scroll bot...no problem man I think I'm going to remove status bar definitely...thank for your help!!

Comment: No problem, sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The status bar has no color: it is transparent. If you want a color to appear through the status bar, put a view with that color at the spot where the status bar will be (that is, the top 20 pixels of your main view).

Notice that when the navigation bar goes away in this screen cast, the background color shows through the status bar:

[image]

That's done entirely with constraint configuration in the storyboard; no code was needed. The top of the table view is effectively pinned to the bottom of the top layout guide, so it stops at the status bar and we see the background color behind it, coloring the status bar.

(However, with a table view the usual approach is to adjust the `contentInset` (and `scrollIndicatorInsets`. The row content will still scroll behind the status bar, but when you're scrolled all the way the top row will be entirely visible below it.)

Comment: I got the same problem I said to #Charles...:/
How can I make this view appear only when my navigation bar is "hidden"  ?

Comment: #matt How can I change my indicator insets and content insets for make this work?

Comment: yes I see but this is not what i need...however you can add this 
"navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true" in viewDidAppear for hide navigation bar on scroll

Comment: Provide me some code...I also have a navigation bar that hide status bar

Comment: As I said in my answer, there is no code. It's all done with constraints in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Charles Truluck's answer, you could do this:

```
if navigationBar.hidden == false {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.view.addSubview(view)
}
```